# Доступ к элементу массива cature<? extends Array[]> без явного преобразования

Tags: java, массивы, generics, преобразование-типов

Есть участок кода:

```
@Override
public void onChanged(Change<? extends AfdxMessageWay, ? extends WayIntWrapper[]> change) {
    if (!isHasError() && change.wasAdded()){
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            if (change.getValueAdded()[i].getIntType()== WayIntWrapper.WayIntType.ERR)
                            hasError.set(true);
        }        
    }
```

В строчке: `if (change.getValueAdded()[i].getIntType()== WayIntWrapper.WayIntType.ERR)`, компилятор ругается:

> Array type expected; found `capture<? extends WayIntWrapper[]>`

Если явно преобразовать capture c помощью `(WayIntType[])`, то все ок, однако "оптимизатор" в IntelliJ IDEA, сразу пишет что Casting is redundant.

Подскажите, почему, происходит такая ошибка конкретно для массивов, ведь если это была бы коллекция - произошло бы неявное преобразование ?

Comment: `change.getValueAdded()[i].getIntType().equals(WayIntWrapper.WayIntType.ERR)` на это тоже ругается ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator в том и дело, что после указания индекса нет доступа к каким либо полям/методам

Comment: `getValueAdded()`  что возвращает ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator capture<? extends WayIntWrapper[]>

Comment: Нашлось вот такое: [JDK-8013843](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8013843). В спецификации написано, что выражение перед скобками в array access expression должно иметь тип массив, но в ней же не написано, является ли `? extends T[]` массивом. Судя по комментариям, какие-то движения делаются, но в jdk-9-ea+147 код все еще не компилируется. Можете попробовать `for (WayIntWrapper w : change.getValueAdded() ) { .. }`, в javac прокатывает, а в eclipse - нет. Или заранее присвоить `WayIntWrapper[] wa = change.getValueAdded()`.

Comment: @zRrr Благодарю. А то просто думал, что это я чего то в принципах программирования на джаве не понимаю. А это оказалось нюансом компилятора.

Comment: @zRrr оформите коммент в виде ответа, чтобы я закрыл вопрос, и для других был очевиден ответ.